# Existence of branches on a tree.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, trees, infinitary-combinatorics

I would like to ask an easy detail about the proof of the following combinatorial question. Suppouse that $\kappa,\lambda$ are infinite regular cardinals and $\lambda<\kappa$. If $T$ is a tree of height $\kappa$ all whose levels have cardinality less than $\lambda$ then $T$ has a branch.

I'm following Todorcevic's Trees and linearly ordered sets survey and he says the following. Take $\delta<\kappa$ a cardinal of cofinality $\lambda$ and a node $t_\delta$ in the $\delta^{th}-$level of $T$. Now, there must exists a $s_\delta$ such that $$\{t\in T: s_\delta< t\}\cap L_\delta(T)=\{t_\delta\}$$
because if not $L_\delta(T)$ would have cardinality $\geq\lambda$.

Is somebody willing justify me in detail this assertion?

Answer (score 2):

**Heavily revised.** (Actually, $\delta$ is any *ordinal* of cofinality $\lambda$ less than $\kappa$.)

The result isn’t quite true as stated. Let $T$ be the set of all $\alpha$-sequences of zeroes for $\alpha<\omega_1$ together with the strings of the form $\sigma^\frown1$ such that $\sigma$ is a countable string of zeroes of limit length. $T$ is a subtree of the complete binary tree of height $\omega_1$ and is an $\omega$-tree of height $\omega_1$. Let $\delta<\omega_1$ be a limit ordinal, and let $t_\delta\in L_\delta(T)$; $t_\delta=\sigma^\frown i$ for the $\delta$-sequence of zeroes and some $i\in\{0,1\}$, and for each $s<_Tt_\delta$, $T^s\cap L_\delta(T)$ contains both $\sigma^\frown 0$ and $\sigma^\frown 1$.

Thus, we want to assume that if $s,t\in L_\alpha(T)$ for some limit ordinal $\alpha$, and

$$\{u\in T:u<_Ts\}=\{u\in T:u<_Tt\}\;,$$

then $s=t$. (This can always be achieved by adding a new level immediately below each limit level of $T$; Todorčević discusses this shortly after the definition of *normal tree*.)

Let $\delta<\kappa$ have cofinality $\lambda$, and fix $t_\delta\in L_\delta(T)$. Let $\langle\alpha_\xi:\xi<\lambda\rangle$ be an increasing $\lambda$-sequence cofinal in $\delta$, and for each $\xi<\lambda$ let $s_\xi$ be the predecessor of $t_\delta$ in $L_{\alpha_\xi}(T)$.

Suppose that

$$|T^{s_\xi}\cap L_\delta(T)|>1$$

for each $\xi<\lambda$. Then for each $\xi<\lambda$ there is a $u_\xi\in T^{s_\xi}\cap(L_\delta(T)\setminus\{t_\delta\})$. For $u\in L_\delta(T)$ let $X(u)=\{\xi<\lambda:u_\xi=u\}$; clearly $s_\xi\le_T u$ for each $\xi\in X(u)$. Thus, if $|X(u)|=\lambda$, $s_\xi\le_T u$ for each $\xi<\lambda$, so $u$ and $t_\delta$ have the same predecessors in $T$, and therefore $u=t_\delta$. But for all $\xi<\lambda$ we have $u_\xi\ne t_\delta$, so $|X(u)|<\lambda$ for each $u\in L_\delta(T)$. And $|L_\delta(T)|<\lambda$, so

$$\left|\,\bigcup_{u\in L_\delta(T)}X(u)\,\right|<\lambda\;,$$

which is absurd, since $\bigcup_{u\in L_\delta(T)}X(u)=\lambda$. Thus, $T^{s_\xi}\cap L_\delta(T)=\{t_\delta\}$ for some $\xi<\lambda$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Anyway, there are some details that I'm not still able to understand. For example, why are there $\lambda$ many $u$ such that $|X(u)|<\lambda$? And also, why is it necessary the last paragraph to get the contradiction ? Is it not enough to say that $L_\delta(T)$ has cardinality $<\lambda$?

Comment: What does mean "share a node"?

Comment: @Ergonvi: Two vertices are part of the same node (‘share a node’) if they have the same predecessors; I’ve removed that terminology from the revised answer. I had to revise the answer quite heavily anyway, because (a) I suddenly realized that I’d been making an assumption that’s not stated in the theorem but does appear to be needed, and (b) the previous version was written in very unclear fashion. See if this version makes better sense.